# Ruby Template Design Pattern folder convention

Tags: ruby, design-patterns

I'm requesting a high-level overview of how to structure the directory of a project using the **Template Design Pattern** in Ruby.

I have a `project` directory with one `venue.rb` file and one folder containing `base.rb`. I see them used a lot in my companies Ruby on Rails project but would like to understand how to structure the project regarding the template design pattern independent of Rails.

### Current Setup:

```
~./project
  +--venue.rb
  +--venue
     |
     +--base.rb
```

## venue.rb

```
require_relative 'venue/base'

class Venue
end

puts "Loaded class Venue:"

a = Venue.new
a.base
```

## ~./project/venue/base.rb

```
module Base
  class Venue
    def base
      puts "base"
    end
  end
end

puts "Loaded module Base:"
```

When I run the `venue.rb` I get:

```
#=> ruby venue.rb
Loaded module Base:
Loaded class Venue:
venue.rb:9:in `<main>': undefined method `base' for #<Venue:0x007fe77209cf20>         
(NoMethodError)
```

I'm pretty sure I've misunderstood inheritance but I believe this should work.

Answer (score 1):

The nice thing about `require` (and `require_relative`) in Ruby is that it's almost equivalent with just substituting the text of the script for the `require`.

So your `venue.rb` is pretty much

```
module Base
  class Venue
    def base
      puts "base"
    end
  end
end

puts "Loaded module Base:"

class Venue
end

puts "Loaded class Venue:"

a = Venue.new
a.base
```

This declares two *different* classes called `Venue` that are in different namespaces: `::Venue` and `Base::Venue`. When you do `a = Venue.new` you are referring to the `::Venue` one that has no `base` method (or any methods, for that matter).

If you want your `Base` module to modify the top-level `Venue`, you need to specifically refer to it:

```
module Base
  class ::Venue
    def base
      puts "base"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the module namespace in `venue.rb` by adding it you can fix the undefined class and also remove the class definition stub.

```
require_relative 'base'

puts "Loaded class Venue:"

a = Base.Venue.new
a.base
```